# Beautiful Soup content empty, not able to Web scraper this webpage, do they block it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get a link from a website, but BeautifulSoup gives me back empty content.
Is the webpage block it or is there some javascript?
How to get the  links?

```
page = requests.get(url='https://finbox.com/NASDAQGS:AAPL')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml").find_all("a", href=True)
```

Comment: What data do you want?

Comment: All <a class="_1fIz- _1JPyC" , href and text

Comment: I meant what data. Do you mean something like "Prominent player in the technology hardware, storage & peripherals industry"?

Comment: yes, all the green text there as "Prominent player in the technology hardware, storage & peripherals industry" as example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get almost all the data via their underlining API. If you look at the Network, `Press (Ctrl + Shift + I), then select Network and filter XHR`, you will see that the webpage gets data from direct calls.

To get data that you are looking for, just observer how the webpage makes GET or POST calls. Data return is json (python dictionary). That means, you do not have to clean it with Beautifulsoup or Selenium.

You only need `requests` or `httpx` for these examples:

```py
import requests

# information about ticker
URL = 'https://makeshift.finbox.com/v4/assets/markets?ticker=NASDAQGS%3AAAPL'
r = requests.get(URL).json()
print(r)

# meta data
r = requests.get("https://makeshift.finbox.com/v4/seo/meta/NASDAQGS:AAPL").json()
print(r)

# post calls
headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36"}
payload = {"category":"view","action":"ViewContent","label":"Company Page","value":0,"data":{"pathname":"/NASDAQGS:AAPL","search":"","ticker":"NASDAQGS:AAPL"}}


r = requests.post("https://finbox.com/_/api/v4/users/events", headers=headers, data=payload).json()
print(r)

# another
payload  = {"query":"\n          query loadAssetPeerBenchmarks ($ticker: String!, $currency: String) {\n            asset: company (ticker: $ticker, currency: $currency) {\n              ticker\n              is_subscribed\n              stats\n            }\n          }\n      ",
            "variables":{"ticker":"NASDAQGS:AAPL"}}

r = requests.post("https://finbox.com/_/api/v4/query?raw=true", headers=headers, json=payload).json()
print(r)
```

Comment: Cool man, how do you scrap to get the <a> tags, is possible to use r?

Comment: I have not used r for scraping, but Python and JS. In the Network, just clear the log, and interact with the webpage to see how data is sent back and forth. with that use headers and responses to see how you can emulate that in Python or JavaScript.

Comment: so i need to follow the Network on Chrome

Comment: The only thing is https://makeshift.finbox.com/v4/assets/checks/NASDAQGS:AAPL give json but not the a.href, right?

Comment: Yes. Filter XHR, then reload page or perform and event. See the GET and POST calls. Hunt by looking at what they return `Preview`. If you see the data you want, clicked `Headers` and see how the call was made.

Comment: May, I ask why do you want the a.href?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229014/discussion-between-prayson-w-daniel-and-devleo).

Answer (score 0):

The page needs JS to render. Try disabling JS in your browser, and the page will refuse to load. `request.get` doesn't run anything. It's just an initial file request. You'll probably want to look into using Selenium with to render the JS in a headless browser.

Comment: Disabling JS nothing change.
Other solutions?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding. You need to run the JavaScript for the page to render the links. People usually do this by requesting the page with a headless browser. Selenium is a popular package that helps you automate headless browsers.

Comment: in selenium is possible to hide the chrome pop-up new window?

Comment: Yeah. There are flags you can set to automatically handle popups.

Comment: I would use requests or httpx only. selenium and beautifulsoup are not needed. If you monitor the network, you can see where data comes from.

Comment: I saw auth cookies when I peeked into the console and decided it wasn't worth investigating considering the fact that OP was fine with the links.

Comment: i guessSelemium is a valid alternative to do faster. I will try both solutions. Both valid solutions

Comment: No, I'd just go with @PraysonW.Daniel 's answer. An API is preferable if there aren't any auth issues